# tfs url in email wrong after migration

Tags: tfs

We migrated our TFS 2017 to TFS 2018 by first using the "Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another" instructions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-clone-hardware) and then upgrading that to TFS 2018 which seemed to go just fine. TFS works, however the URLs in the emails that go out regarding work items are still pointing at the old server.  The only URL that I can find to change is the Public URL on the Application Tier, which is already correct. In the message header on the emails that are sent out, the old server also appears to be the sending domain: 
In-Reply-To: Tfs.WorkItem.Project.#####@oldservername

I can't find references to that old server anywhere though. Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find the issue.  The tbl_AccessMapping table in the database for the Project Collection had different values in it than the tbl_AccessMapping table in the tfs_teamfoundationconfiguration database (specifically the accesspoint field).  tfs_teamfoundationconfiguration was correct, so we synced those correct values over to the Project Collection database.

This took some time to take effect, I assume due to caching. Restarting IIS would likely fix it quicker.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me in my TFS 2015 - 2019 upgrade when certain Project Collections could not be accessed via an assigned domain name. Leaving this comment in case anyone else has the same problem as me.